# Добавить элементы к элементу

Tags: javascript

К элементу `<ul id="test"></ul>` нужно добавить 3 `<li></li>` элемента, выбрать `<ul>` элемент с помощью `id = "test"`, создать каждый новый `<li></li>` элемент с помощью метода `createElement()` и добавить к списку с помощью методу `appendChild()`.

Comment: У елемент <ul id="test"></ul> нужно додать 3 <li></li> елементы выбрать <ul> елемент с помощю id = “test” создать каждый новый <li></li> елемент с помощю методу createElement() и дообавить к списку с помощю методу appendChild()

Answer (score 0):

Надеюсь, это то, что требуется)

```js
const ul = document.querySelector('#test');

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  ul.appendChild(document.createElement('li'));
}
```

```html
<ul id="test"></ul>
```